# Series $e^1+e^2+\:...\:+e^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

Is there a way to calculate this not term-by term ?

$$E_n =e^1+e^2+...+e^n$$

I tried developping :

$$E_n = \sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1^k}{k!}+\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{2^k}{k!}+...+\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{n^k}{k!}$$

It can be shortened to :

$$E_n = \sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{k!}$$

$$E_n = \sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}i^k}{k!}$$

Now, I don't know if there's a way to continue.

I searched around the internet and stumbled across the Faulhaber formula. Does this can help ?

Edit : ok i'm stupid I forgot about the geometric series :(

Comment: I think there should be a formula to express the numerator in a more compact way

Comment: Why not a geometric series? This is a common summation.

Comment: Response to edit: no, not stupid. Everyone misses easy stuff from time to time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each term is being multiplied by $e$, so this is called [the partial sum of a geometric series](http://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/how-to-find-the-partial-sum-of-a-geometric-sequence/), so the formula is:
$$E_n=e\left(\frac{1-e^n}{1-e}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

If:${a_n},{b_n}$ are sequences,and $a_{n+1}-a_n=A,\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=B;A,B $ are constant and $B\neq 1$

Let:$S_n=\sum_\limits{k=1}^n{a_k\cdot b_k}$  ,then we have:$$B·S_n=\sum_\limits{k=1}^n a_k ·b_{k+1}$$
So:$$(1-B)·{S_n}=\sum_\limits{k=1}^n {(a_{k+1}-a_k)}b_{k+1}+a_1 b_1-a_n\cdot b_{n+1}$$ $$=A\sum_\limits{k=2}^n b_{k}+a_1 b_1-a_n\cdot b_{n+1}$$ $$=A\frac{b_2(1-B^n)}{1-B}+a_1 b_1-a_n\cdot b_{n+1}$$$$S_n=A\frac{b_2(1-B^n)}{(1-B)^2}+\frac{a_1 b_1-a_n\cdot b_{n+1}}{1-B}$$